# How do I clear the dropdown of logins from the sql server 2008 management studio connection prompt?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've connected to a few databases once and only once and will never need to again, however they clutter up the dropdown of logins available to select.

How can I reset the lists of servers and logins from the connection prompt in SQL Server Management Studio Express 2008?

Answer (score 5):

In SSMS 2008, if you rename the `SqlStudio.bin` file to, say, `SqlStudio.BAK`, then SSMS will recreate this file upon re-opening the application. All servers and logins will be forgotten.

[Reference](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/11/05/sql-server-clear-drop-down-list-of-recent-connection-from-sql-server-management-studio/)

Answer (score 3):

For SQL Server Management Studio 2008, this data is apparently stored in...

**%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\SqlStudio.bin**

Be advised that this is a binary file.  These values are associated with an object named **Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UserSettings.ServerConnectionSettings**, which is some sort of managed collection object.

That's where they live.  I'd modify this file at your own peril, and make a backup of it just in case.  :)

Comment: This is true for Sql Server 2014 too

Answer (score 1):

You can very carefully delete (or - even better - rename) the file **mru.dat** in:

> %home%\Application
>   Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\Tools\Shell\

**NOTE**: my version il 2005, so you might find your path is slightly different.

Comment: hmm, 2008 on vista I look here: 

C:\Users\\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell 

but can find no mru.dat

Comment: @ DannyT seen The Lazy DBA's answer below? the file to look for (2k8 on Vista) is SqlStudio.bin

Answer (score 0):

Vista user can update the DialogSettings.xml. This file can avilable in the following location

C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Shell

Comment: unfortunately I have no such file in the 2008 version:
C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell